# How can I get the correct referer via JavaScript if the referrer uses https?

Tags: javascript, html, referrer

I use `document.referrer` to read the referrer url via JavaScript e.g. if a user clicked a google search result link and lands on my website:

```
http://www.google.com -> Click on search result -> redirect -> http://www.mysite.com => document.redirect returns correct referrer
```

Now, this works fine as long as the google search result was delivered via http **but** if instead httpS is used, `document.referrer` is always empty:

```
https://www.google.com -> Click on search result -> redirect -> http:/www.mysite.com => document.redirect is empty
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: You are not going to get the data: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39645/document-referrer-from-google-searches-only-showing-https-www-google-com-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you search from https://www.google.com, websites you visit from our organic search listings will still know that you came from Google, but won't receive information about each individual query.

Please read: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html