# Why can't I get the full URL from a Google search

Tags: javascript

I search Google for a phrase which brings up my website.

Google shows a URL similar to

```
https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=my%20search
```

This brings up my website. On the landing page of my website, I have the following javascript

```
alert(document.referral);
```

This shows me the value

```
https://www.google.co.uk/
```

No querystring!

Research suggests the issue is likely due to my website being HTTP but both Google and my website use HTTPS

Why can I not get the search phrase from the query string?

**Edit**

Based upon the links I've been provided (thanks) I can  see what you are claiming the issue is. Google doesn't allow it! However, I'm not sure I agree with this - there are *many* web analytical programs which provide this information. The company I have used (which admittedly can only provide keywords for 5% of all visitors) can do this... And I only embed some javascript. I can only assume it's because visitors can home HTTP:://google as opposed to HTTPS::google

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682718/javascript-document-referrer-with-full-querystring

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this document: http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/the-impact-of-google-encrypted-search/

It apparently has something to do with google running HTTPS. on my local tomcat server running HTTP, i get 
http://servername/tools/errorlog.jsp?env=Prod&logType=EXTAUTHLOG when running 
`alert(document.referrer)` in a console

Duplicate of:
[How can I get the correct referer via JavaScript if the referrer uses https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971264/how-can-i-get-the-correct-referer-via-javascript-if-the-referrer-uses-https) ??